# Remote server has both libmysql drivers and mysqlnd drivers but it defaults to libmysql. How can I config server so phpMyAdmin shows it uses mysqlnd

Tags: php, configuration, phpmyadmin

I have been trying to get my database to work remotely for about 2 weeks now. I have had extensive contact with my remote server provider and from what I gather I need to configure my php application (I think through phpMyAdmin, but I am not so sure anymore...) to use the mysqlnd driver to get my php to work remotely (it works perfectly at home, using XAMPP and phpMyAdmin). I make extensive use of the mysqlnd driver so I would really like this to work on the remote server too.

I can actually see the problem on the first page of phpMyAdmin; on the Web Server information space it says:

At home:
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: b________c77 $

On remote server: 
Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73

How can I get the remote php to use the mysqlnd driver? (Do I need to recompile PHP? if so I guess I am going to have to pay my web provider, right?)

I have created a page with php code shown and a sample of the result I am looking for (there should be two batches of results if it worked...). Right at the top there is also a link to my phpinfo() results.

My server provider said I can fix this, or they can, provided I pay them a fair amount of money.

Comment: You'll have to let on a bit more about the server setup (distro, php.ini and conf.d/, relevant packages). Otherwise, go for the paid support.

Comment: Your question has an [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27007281/edit).

Comment: The info about the (Unix) server is:
cpsrvd 11.44.1.22.
Versione del client del database: libmysql - 5.1.73.
Estensione PHP: mysqli.

The php.ini is the same as the one I use on the local server (which works fine), but I have to admit there does not seem to be a line in my php.ini to direct it to mysqlnd.. but then it works locally, so why not on the remote server?

As for the conf.d/  I just don't know where I could find this on the server.

There are no other packages I am using on my server (just phpmyadmin and MariaDB really)

Comment: Sorry about my ignorance, I am self tought..
In fact I thought PHP was pretty easy, until I had to upload it to the remote server! I have been stuck on this longer than I thought possible...

Comment: Incidentally PHP is run as CGI on the server, so I do have access to most if not all settings

Comment: None of these infos are helpful in any way. You seem to base your question on the misunderstanding that the mysql driver variant within PHP has anything to do with remote socket connections to the mysql server. It hasn't.

Comment: Thanks Mario, your comments have pointed me in the right direction. Although, I am starting to think I can't fix this without paying my server's people (Because I am not allowed to recompile php by myself on the server)